# Calling a Function within a secondary Function, or calling a Function defined within a larger Function

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

I'm trying to use python to create a small look up program, that would show all the current prices of a theoretical portfolio, and then offer the option to basically refresh your portfolio, or look up a new quote of your choice.

I can get everything to work in the program, the problem I'm having is with the defined functions.

If you look at run_price1(), you'll notice that it is identical to that of run_price(); however run_price() is located within the update function.

If I take it out of the update function, the update function doesn't work.  If I don't also list it somewhere outside of the update function, the later user input doesn't work.

The question:  I am looking for either a way to call a function that is defined within another function, or a way to use a previously defined function inside of a secondary function.

My code:

```
import mechanize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def run_price1():

    myBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
    htmlPage=myBrowser.open(web_address)
    htmlText=htmlPage.get_data()
    mySoup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)

    myTags = mySoup.find_all("span", id=tag_id)

    myPrice = myTags[0].string

    print"The current price of, {} is: {}".format(ticker.upper(), myPrice)



def update():

    my_stocks = ["aapl","goog","sne","msft","spy","trgt","petm","fslr","fb","f","t"]

    counter = 0

    while counter < len(my_stocks):

        web_address = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}".format(my_stocks[counter])
        ticker = my_stocks[counter]
        #'yfs_l84_yhoo' - that 1(one) is really a lowercase "L"
        tag_id = "yfs_l84_{}".format(ticker.lower())
        def run_price():

            myBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
            htmlPage=myBrowser.open(web_address)
            htmlText=htmlPage.get_data()
            mySoup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)

            myTags = mySoup.find_all("span", id=tag_id)
            myPrice = myTags[0].string
            print"The current price of, {} is: {}".format(ticker.upper(), myPrice)

        run_price()

        counter=counter+1

update()        

ticker = ""

while ticker != "end":

    ticker = raw_input("Type 'update', to rerun portfolio, 'end' to stop program, or a lowercase ticker to see price: ")
    web_address = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}".format(ticker.lower())
    tag_id = "yfs_l84_{}".format(ticker.lower())

    if ticker == "end":
        print"Good Bye"

    elif ticker == "update":
        update()

    else:
        run_price1()
```

Comment: Why not just call `run_price1` instead of `run_price` and remove the latter altogether? You don't *have* to define it inside of `update`.

Comment: I tried that, I would prefer to do that, but it doesn't work.  I get the error - NameError: global name 'web_address' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `run_price1()` from the `update()` function, where you now call `run_price`.

Functions defined at the top of a module are global in the module, so other functions can simply refer to those by name and call them.

Any value that your function needs *does* need to be passed in as an argument:

```
def run_price1(web_address, tag_id):
    # ...

def update():
    my_stocks = ["aapl","goog","sne","msft","spy","trgt","petm","fslr","fb","f","t"]

    counter = 0

    while counter < len(my_stocks):

        web_address = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}".format(my_stocks[counter])
        ticker = my_stocks[counter]
        #'yfs_l84_yhoo' - that 1(one) is really a lowercase "L"
        tag_id = "yfs_l84_{}".format(ticker.lower())

        run_price1(web_address, tag_id)

        counter=counter+1
```

Comment: That's how I had written it originally, it gives me - NameError: global name 'web_address' is not defined

Comment: I see what you did, I didn't notice that you added web_address to the parentheses. If I add that, I get IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @LoWri: Ah, `tag_id` is another parameter you need to pass in.

Comment: Thanks! I passed in the ticker variable as well, and now it all works.  I think I'm beginning to understand the use of function variables, thank you!